# Gradle Advanced Build Plugin: Cannot invoke canRead()?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to use [Gradle Advanced Build Version Plugin](https://github.com/moallemi/gradle-advanced-build-version) in my app. I did as described in the GitHub page:

1. I added this code in my app's build.gradle:

   ```
   buildscript {
     repositories {
         jcenter()
     }

     dependencies {
         classpath 'org.moallemi.gradle.advanced-build-version:gradle-plugin:1.5.0'
     }
   }
   apply plugin: 'org.moallemi.advanced-build-version'
   ```
2. Then, at the end of the same file, I configured `advancedVersioning` like this:

   ```
   advancedVersioning {
       outputOptions {
           renameOutput true
           nameFormat '${projectName}-${buildType}-${versionName}'
       }
   }
   ```

However, when I `Generate a Signed APK`, I get an error while executing `:app:assembleRelease` task:

```
Error:

02:06:47.075 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
02:06:47.076 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE:
Build failed with an exception. 
02:06:47.076 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
02:06:47.077 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
02:06:47.077 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] A problem occurred
configuring project ':app'.
02:06:47.077 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
Cannot invoke method canRead() on null object
02:06:47.078 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
02:06:47.078 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * Try: 
02:06:47.078 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Run with  --stacktrace option to
get the stack trace.
```

This is on Android Studio 1.3 with gradle plugin 1.2.3. I tried moving the code in step #1 to the Project's build.gradle but I still get the same error.

Comment: version 1.5.1 fixed this issue

Comment: @moallemi I experience the same issue on 1.5.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a simple bug that causes `NullPointerException`.

The `versionPropsFile` property of the `VersionCodeOptions` class is only initialized in the `getVersionCode` getter.

But the plugin tries to access this property before it calls to `getVersionCode`, and thus receiving a null file reference, which crashes when it check whether it `canRead()`.

The workaround is pretty simple: All you need to do is to make a dummy call to the `getVersionCode` getter right after you configure the plugin, like this:

**In the project's build.gradle:**

```
advancedVersioning {
    nameOptions {
    }
    codeOptions {
        versionCodeType VersionCodeType.AUTO_INCREMENT_ONE_STEP
        dependsOnTasks 'release'
    }
}

println advancedVersioning.versionCode
```

By printing the version code I'm invoking the getter and thus creating the file object.

Comment: I would to add that in case you also change the way your versionCode behaves then you should already use something like 
`def appVersionCode = advancedVersioning.versionCode` and then set
`versionCode  appVersionCode`

,in that case there is no need in the `println` statement